# Why is my bone not attaching to the vertex group of the same name?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I have vertex groups named Hand-R and Hand-L. I have bones named Hand-R and Hand-L. The bones do not attach to the vertex groups. All the other vertex groups were attached to the matching bone, but not the hands. What am I doing wrong here, and what do I need to do to fix it?

[image]

Blend file: https://workupload.com/file/vFy37HyfmBB

Comment: Have you assigned vertices to these groups? Do you have an armature deform modifier on the mesh object?

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: @L0Lock The vertices are definitely assigned to the vertex groups, I can select and deselect them using the appropriate vertex group. The object is parented to the armature and all other bones and joints work as expected.

Comment: @moonboots How can I share files on StackExchange?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or use another platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: @moonboots https://workupload.com/file/vFy37HyfmBB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the *Deform* option of these bones:

[image]

Comment: @moonbots Thank you, that fixed it!